How can I create a Dev Container for a .NET Framework 4.8 project with SQL Server and Microsoft Sync Framework?
I am working on a project that uses:

.NET Framework 4.8
SQL Server
Microsoft Sync Framework

I am trying to set up a Dev Container for this project using Docker and Visual Studio Code, but I haven't found a way to create a container for .NET Framework 4.8.
From what I understand, Visual Studio Code's Dev Containers extension primarily supports Linux-based containers, and it seems that Windows containers are not supported by the extension.
Is it possible to create a Dev Container for a .NET Framework 4.8 application? If so, could you provide guidance on how to do it?
I'm new to Dev Containers and would really appreciate any ideas or solutions you can share!

You can't use .NET Framework in a Linux container. You could switch Docker to Windows Containers but then you'd have to find a base Windows container image.

@PanagiotisKanavos Can't we use FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 as base image with windows containers?
